# grunt-closure-compiler modules throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using [this](https://github.com/treyone/grunt-closure-compiler) fork of grunt-closure-compiler task to build multiple files with closure compiler.

I have the following compiler flags set:

```
--module_output_path_prefix .\  --js lib\test\mod-c.js  --module test_mod__c:1  --js lib\test\mod-d.js  --module test_mod__d:1  --js lib\test\mod-b.js  --module test_mod__b:1:test_mod__c,test_mod__d  --js lib\test\mod-a.js  --module test_mod__a:1:test_mod__b,test_mod__d  --compilation_level "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" --language_in "ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT"
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <test_mod__c, test_mod__d>
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:317)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:289)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.JSModuleGraph.getRootModule(JSModuleGraph.java:150)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.AnalyzePrototypeProperties.<init>(AnalyzePrototypeProperties.java:122)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CrossModuleMethodMotion.<init>(CrossModuleMethodMotion.java:79)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.DefaultPassConfig$97.create(DefaultPassConfig.java:2170)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass.process(PhaseOptimizer.java:285)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$Loop.process(PhaseOptimizer.java:458)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer.process(PhaseOptimizer.java:217)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.optimize(Compiler.java:1901)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compileInternal(Compiler.java:681)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.access$000(Compiler.java:89)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$2.call(Compiler.java:632)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$2.call(Compiler.java:629)
at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerExecutor$2.call(CompilerExecutor.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

According to a few sources I can find, this is often caused by an invalid dependency tree, but I can't see why it's wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing it may be because you have 2 base modules? You might try creating a common base module for `test_mod__c` and `test_mod__d`. Such a base module is allowed to have zero files to support just this case.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by base modules? As I understand it, `a` depends on `b` and `d`, and `b` depends on `c` and `d`. The entry point for the code is `a`.

Comment: It's too long for a comment - I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output modules must describe a tree. That requirement means a single base module from which all other modules descend. A base module is a module that depends on no others.

Your flags list 2 base modules:

- `--module test_mod__c:1`
- `--module test_mod__d:1`

These are base modules because they depend on no others. From your comment, I think you may be describing the tree backwards. Based on your comment that `a` is the entry point, I believe the tree you want would look like this:

```
test_mod__a
└─ test_mod__b
|  ├─ test_mod__c
└─ └─ test_mod__d
```

Here are the flags that describe this tree:

```
--module_output_path_prefix .\
--js lib\test\mod-a.js --module test_mod__a:1
--js lib\test\mod-b.js --module test_mod__b:1:test_mod__a
--js lib\test\mod-c.js --module test_mod__c:1:test_mod__b
--js lib\test\mod-d.js --module test_mod__d:1:test_mod__a,test_mod__b
```

Also, you may want to use the [official npm version of the compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler) - it now includes a grunt plugin and supports the `--module` flags.

*Disclaimer: I manage the publication of Closure-compiler to npm and am the plugin author*

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation on this anywhere? Couldn't find anything that explained the Closure module system, and I've got a grunt task converting from the ImpactJS module system to it. Looks like they work in opposite directions, so my grunt task is going to need a fairly major rewrite.

Comment: There's a difference between output modules and JS modules. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules. If you can point me to some examples of that transformation, I can give you more insight. I'm the primary compiler dev on module interoperation.